# Pandas Error: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'head'

Tags: python, pandas

I am new to python specially pandas library.This is my code.

```
file_path = "C:\\Users\\Roshaan\\Desktop\\"
b = os.listdir(file_path)
f = 1
for file in b:
     def func():
          print("format not supported")
     #prints file name i.e test.csv
     print(file)
     path = file_path + file 
     df = pd.read_csv(path) if file.endswith(('.csv', '.tsv')) else func()
     print (df.head(1))
```

This is the error I am facing.

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'head'
```

Comment: because `func()` is returning Nothing you are just printing 'format not supported' and your this condition is failed `file.endswith(('.csv', '.tsv'))`

Comment: show us full code

Comment: It's not finding any file matching your criteria.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because, as mentioned in the comments, the `func()` is not returning anything. So when a file does not end with `.csv` or `.tsv`, df is actually None.

To fix this you can do the following:

```
file_path = "C:\\Users\\Roshaan\\Desktop\\"
b = os.listdir(file_path)
     
for file in b:
    #prints file name i.e test.csv
    print(file)
    path = file_path + file 
    if file.endswith(('.csv', '.tsv')):
        df = pd.read_csv(path)
        print (df.head(1))
    else:
        print("format not supported")
```

Comment: Thanks but i wanted to use the ternary expression for some reason.

Comment: That would make the code really unreadable. But you can write something like: `print(pd.read_csv(path).head(1) if file.endswith(('.csv', '.tsv')) else "format not supported" )`